# Is there a way to use value from one dictionary to search on another?

Tags: python, django, dictionary

Im setting up a Django view where im generating some card based on how many there are on a given dictionary. Each of those cards will contain different information depending on who they are, that info is static and stored locally. The way i have the main dictionary setup allows me to loops thru all the cards but i cant figure out how to then get the card's individual data.

Maybe foolishly tried to use a value from a dictionary to traverse another one. possibly my dictionary structure is my blocker but i cant come up with any other way.

### views.py

location --> URL variable

cards --> data pulled from database

vlans --> data pulled from local json file

```
def home_view(request, location):
    cards = Site.objects.get(sites=location.upper()).site_cards.all().values('cards')
    cards_dict = {c: c for c in [d['cards'] for d in list(cards)]}
    vlans = json.load(open('allvendors/static/json/vlans.json'))
    selected_site_vlans = vlans[location]
    home = {
        "site": location,
        "cards": cards_dict,
        "vlans": selected_site_vlans
    }
    return render(request, 'allvendors/home.html', {"home": home})
```

### home.html

home.vlans.***card***.vlan --> Foolish attempt at using key from one dict on another. See data structure being passed to the template below.

```
{% for card in home.cards %}
        <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow shadow">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 id="whatfor" class="my-0 font-weight-normal">{{ card|title }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">Vlan:
                    <small class="text-muted">
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">
                            {{ home.vlans.card.vlan }}
                        </a>
                    </small>
                </h1>
                <a class="text-decoration-none" href="{{ card|lower }}/">
                    <button id="seedata" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary">See
                        Database</button>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

### home

```
{
   'site':'A',
   'cards':{
      'networkA':'networkA',
      'networkB':'networkB'
   },
   'vlans':{
      'networkA':{
         'vlan':'101',
      },
      'networkB':{
         'vlan':'102',
      }
}
```

Each card should display the VLAN that corresponds to it so a card called networkA should display inside the value under vlans.networkA.vlan, but i cant come up with how to do so. Any help is welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way too complicated explanation, not sure if I understood, but here's a try:

```
vlans = json.load(open('allvendors/static/json/vlans.json'))
cards_dict = {c: vlans[location][c] for c in [d['cards'] for d in list(cards)]}
home = {
    "site": location,
    "cards": cards_dict,
}
```

And `{{ card.vlan }}` in template.

Comment: Thanks @ipakela thats is definitely onto something, now home context object looks like each card has all the vlans: 

https://pastebin.com/xKkxzCP0

How can i make it look like the card with name networkA only gets the vlans with name networkA, networkB with networkB and so on, like so:

 https://pastebin.com/25Z8caDN

Comment: Yep, sorry, forgot that, I edited my answer and appended `[c]`.

Comment: Excellent, looks exactly as described, strange thing tho even with the proper data structure like that, card.vlan doesn't output anything on the template yet card by itself does, im going to have to dive dive since it probably a different issue. Thanks a lots @ipakela